# How can I grep JSON record with specific values in Linux

Tags: regex, linux, unix, grep

Lets say I have this in the same file:

```
{
  "city": "NY",
  "car": "ford",
  "whatever": "whatever",
  "whatever": "whatever",
  "day": "friday",
  "mood": "good",
  "whatever": "whatever",
  "whatever": "whatever",
}
{
  "whatever": "whatever",
  "city": "NY",
  "car": "ford",
  "day": "monday",
  "whatever": "whatever",
  "whatever": "whatever",
  "whatever": "whatever",
  "mood": "good",
  "whatever": "whatever",
}
```

How can I grep only that record in which I have `"day": "monday"`?
I've have actually tried a lot of different ways, for example `grep -Po '{[^*]+\n.+day\": \"monday.+[^*]}'`
So eventually I want to get this:

```
{
  "whatever": "whatever",
  "city": "NY",
  "car": "ford",
  "day": "monday",
  "whatever": "whatever",
  "whatever": "whatever",
  "whatever": "whatever",
  "mood": "good",
  "whatever": "whatever",
}
```

Comment: Since it is JSON, you should consider using [JSON-specific tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools).

Comment: thanks for the good tip, I'll take a look at this

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code.

Comment: I've have actually tried a lot of different ways, for example `grep -Po '{[^*]+\n.+day\": \"monday.+[^*]}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to parse the JSON file, for example having this file:

```
[{
    "city": "NY",
    "car": "ford",
    "whatever": "whatever",
    "day": "friday",
    "mood": "good"
}, {
    "whatever": "whatever",
    "city": "NY",
    "car": "ford",
    "day": "monday",
    "mood": "good"
}]
```

If you just want to get the dictionary having the day equal to monday:

```
jq '.[] |  select(.day | contains("monday"))' file.json
```

It will return:

```
{
  "whatever": "whatever",
  "city": "NY",
  "car": "ford",
  "day": "monday",
  "mood": "good"
}
```

Comment: This is the appropriate tool for the job. manual: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/